# How can I set the focus to a ListBox properly on load if it uses databinding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, focus

I usually call `myControl.Focus()` in the Loaded event handler, but this doesn't seem to work for a `ListBox` which is databound to a list of custom objects. When I start my application, the `ListBox`'s first item is selected but the focus is elsewhere.

I thought this could be because the focus is being set before the databound items are loaded into it... but the following code shows that there are indeed items because `ctrlItemsCount` shows the number 8.

How can I set the initial focus in this situation, and what is the correct place to set initial focus usually?

```
private void onLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (ctrlCountries.Items.Count > 0) {
             ctrlItemsCount.Text = ctrlCountries.Items.Count;
             ctrlCountries.SelectedIndex = 0;
             FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, ctrlCountries);
        }

  }
```

**EDIT:** I have moved this code to the loaded event for the actual `ListBox` itself. It almost works - the focus is now on the `ListBox`, but I still need to press keyboard DOWN once before item #0 has the keyboard cursor. In other words, the focus, or cursor, is 1 notch above item #0 for some reason:

```
private void onCountriesLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    ctrlCountries.SelectedIndex = 0;
    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, ctrlCountries);
    Keyboard.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to focus the first element in the list box you have to set the focus to the first *ListBoxItem* container. For example:

```
if (myListBox.Items.Count > 0)
{ 
   ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
   FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this /* focus scope region */, item);
}
```

You still have to make sure though, that the *ListBox* control has first received its *Loaded* event. There are a number of other events that are useful for handling list box item related updates. Have a look at the [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: It works! Almost... It works 100% as it should if I use "Keyboard.Focus(item);" instead of the FocusManager. This is odd because MSDN says the FocusManager will set the logical focus AND attempt to set the keyboard focus. Am I learning the correct lesson that Keyboard.Focus(item) is what I should always use then?

Answer (score 2):

The `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement` method gives logical focus, but not keyboard focus. You can use the [`Keyboard.Focus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.focus.aspx) method to give keyboard focus to an element. Have a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx) for more details about focus management in WPF.

Comment: I added Keyboard.Focus(ctrlCountries); and it doesn't work.
Note that if I add a button click event handler which sets focus with the focus manager alone, it works.

Comment: In other words, the following code does not put the focus on the listbox first item:
private void onLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
                FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, ctrlCountries);
                Keyboard.Focus(ctrlCountries);
        }

Comment: Do it after the ListBox is fully loaded (i.e. when the ctrlCountries.Loaded event occurs)

Comment: Thanks, this is much better now. But the cursor is still on the outside of the ListBox (ie. its border seems to have the focus), so I have to hit DOWN before the first listbox item is selected.

Comment: I think you may try to set the logical focus before also:
var item = (ListBoxItem)listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(selectedIndex);
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, item);
Keyboard.Focus(item);