# WPF: how to auto scroll to my first ListViewItem when form load

Tags: wpf, listview, focus

So i am build simple `Clipboard` manager.
Every `ListViewItem` come from `Clipboard.GetText` and my application minimize to `Tray` and when double click on its `Icon` the application jump and i want to focus become on the first `ListViewItem` in order to be able to navigate with `Up & Down` arrows.

This is my `ListView`:

```
ListView myListView;
```

**Model List:**

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Clipboards
```

**Window Loaded event:**

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (viewModel.Clipboards.Count != 0)
            myListView.ScrollIntoView(myListView.Items[0]);
        myListView.Focus();
     }
```

So currently when i open int the first time the application, the `Focus` is not on any `ListViewItem` and in the next time the focus is on the last selected/click  `ListViewItem` and not on the first one.

Comment: Have you tried using [Focus Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21891179/2029607) for this? Also if the ListView is bound to a ViewModel then you could control if there is anything selected without handling the code behind or relying on puny loaded events.

Comment: Can i have simple code example of what you talking ?

Comment: Sure. `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Clipboards}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClipboard}" Name="lst" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=lst}"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your ViewModel in the code behind. This is not good MVVM standard.

Maybe this could be helpful
[How can I set the focus to a ListBox properly on load if it uses databinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283143/how-can-i-set-the-focus-to-a-listbox-properly-on-load-if-it-uses-databinding)

Answer (score -1):

From what I see you are not focusing any `ListViewItem` but the `ListView` itself. I think this is your mistake. To focus  the item you have to get it's container. The objects in the `ItemsSource` are actually the data itself and no the `UIElement` to render. To draw this data or add it to the visual tree for rendering, the `ItemsControl` will generate a container for the data e.g. a `ListViewItem`. Only the UIElement can receive focus, that's why the `UIElement` exposes the Focus() method. You have to use the `ItemContainerGenarator` to retrieve this container for your data:

```
  ListView myListView;
  (myListView.ItemsPanel as VirtualizingPanel)?.BringIndexIntoViewPublic(0);
  myListView.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(
    () => 
    {
      ListBoxItem dataContainer = myListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListBoxItem;
      dataContainer?.Focus();
    }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

This example will move the focus to the first element in the ListView.

Comment: That wouldn't (or possibly wouldn't) work if you are using virtualization (which is the default) since containers get destroyed when scrolled out of view and you'll get a null exception. You'd have to scroll item 0 into view first, then wait for the container to be generated. Only then can you set focus to it.

Comment: This time you are right. When virtualization is used we have to take care that the requested item container is generated before we can access it. This time your comment has some value. This is how we do it. That's professional behavior.

Comment: Yeah, feels like you are stalking me. I am that guy that you are trying to tell to manage my controls from within the view model and that code-behind free files are mandatory to MVVM. But no problem.

Comment: oh.. I didn't pay attention to the name... and no, that's not what I said at all... you were too busy going on your rant to read I guess lol... but yes, I'll stick to my statement about the 2nd part... if you are using code behind you aren't packaging stuff correctly. It's simply not needed and its poor design to split the logic. I'll also stick to my other point about your approach being bad since you are tightly coupling a bunch of things. But hey... you work at BMW, so what do I know lol...

Comment: Btw, your fixed code still won't work since containers are generated asynchronously. All your code will do now is nothing since all the null checks will fail.